# Razor- how to display message box?

Tags: razor

I am new to Razor. My application is not MVC.

What I am trying to achieve is to inform user that posting data to database was successful.

I do not want to re-direct user, all I want is to display a good looking message box.

I made quite a lot of research and I found these:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT> alert('Hello this is an Alert')</SCRIPT>");
```

and this

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Message');</script>");
```

They both display message but a very bad looking one.

Question:

How to display a good looking message box using razor syntax?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default browser message box, you can't style it.

If you want a nice looking message you need to style a custom one using html/css/JavaScript.

E.g. you could use a jquery-ui see [jquery-ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

My preference is [ALERTIFY JS](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)